# Whats up with my grapevine

Tags: diagnosis, soil-amendment, pest-damage, grape-vine, stress

Im located in south Jersey
Soil is clay but was amended with leafcompost, micronutrients stuff and topped with 4" woodchips. Only watered it when planted and monitored the moister level before watering again...So I planted this grapevine in spring. It started from a little twig was growing beautifully health all green and vibrant but like two weeks ago started seeing leafs drying up see below pix(the leafs that are blotchy, only looks better in pix but it's really yellower). I don't see any pest or signs that could cause a stress.
Please let me know what could cause this and if there's anything I need to be doing to prep for winter.[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions?